# Update installs a beta version

Tags: updating, composer

I'm trying to update Drupal from 9.1.8 to 9.1.9. However, running a composer update jumps to 9.2-beta2. I'm not sure how to fix it so that it sticks to the recommended version.

My composer.json has this...

```
"drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^9.1.0",
"drupal/core-project-message": "^9.1.0",
"drupal/core-recommended": "^9.1.0",
```

[image]

How can I prevent my sites from updating past 9.1.x? It used to be a bit simpler with `drupal/core` but I know that's not the recommended package to use anymore.

Comment: See [`minimum-stability`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability) (and `prefer-stable` immediately after it)

Comment: Damn. You're right. I had `prefer-stable` set, but my `minimum-stability` was set to `dev`. Thanks!